# Woocommerce - display attribute values as a dropdown field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I've got a question regarding woocommerce and its attributes. I've got about 10 attributes like: speed, weight, color, Engine etc. What I'm trying to do is to create a search form on one page, and user after filling/selecting proper options via select fields will search for products.

Yet I've stucked with a piece of code which is suppose to create such dropdown (the one which will display ALL VALUES of specific attribute).

Code:

```
<?php
$subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_naped');
if ($subheadingvalues): ?>
<select>
    <?php foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>">
            <?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Main issue of this code? Simply doesn't work - displays nothing. I've double checked the attribute name in woocommerce dashboard and its name indeed is pa_naped (engine). Why its not working?

Secondly, what if I would like to make same thing but for ALL selected by me attributes (mentioned above). Should I make a kind of array or sth?

Comment: with this you code you are getting the terms for specific product `$product->id` 
as i understand from your question you are creating from in separated page to search in all products, if am correct then this code will not give you the expected result and you need to do your form in different way, however if you want result only for single product the use `var_dump` to check if you are getting any product id in the first place.

Comment: @kashalo - you are correct. Do you know how to change the code?

Comment: yes sure i will write the code to get all values and print there names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all values of a term you need to use `get_terms()`

so your functions should look like the following:

```
$subheadingvalues = get_terms('pa_naped', array(
'hide_empty' => false,
));
?> <select>
    <?php foreach ($subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>">
        <?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

[Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did for `dietary-preference` taxonomy.

```
$attrargs = array(
    'show_option_all'   => '',
    'show_option_none'  => 'Dieta',
    'orderby'           => 'id',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'show_count'        => 1,
    'hide_empty'        => 1,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'exclude'           => '',
    'echo'              => 1,
    'selected'          => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => 0,
    'name'              => 'pa_dietary-preference',
    'id'                => 'pa_dietary-preference',
    'class'             => 'pa_dietary-preference',
    'depth'             => 0,
    'tab_index'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'          => 'pa_dietary-preference',
    'hide_if_empty'     => false,
    'option_none_value' => -1,
    'value_field'       => 'term_id',
    'required'          => true,
);

<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $attrargs ); ?>
```